# How to list all repositories in AWS ECR public registry gallery

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr

How to list all repositories in AWS ECR public registry `https://gallery.ecr.aws/` using AWS ecr CLI

For a private registry we use `https://<aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com`. What should we use for accessing images under `gallery.ecr.aws`

Answer (score 0):

In the private repository you can use `aws ecr describe-repositories`.  Make sure you have aws CLI installed and configured too.

However, with the public repository you can access them directly from the link you have provided already https://gallery.ecr.aws/ or use the option `ecr-public`.